# how to judge the navigator push is complete?

Tags: flutter

I want to Calculated some offset in state .

```
WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback()
```

and use key to get offset in global.

```
RenderBox renderBox = key.currentContext.findRenderObject();
Offset offset = renderBox.localToGlobal(Offset.zero);
```

but this offset Every time is different, deviation to the right of different values.
so i guess it's related to navigator's animation.
did flutter have callback like navigator push completed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [RouteObserver](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/RouteObserver-class.html) class to listen to changes in routes and then do some stuff according to your use case.